# Storm: Get the top ten users in real time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-storm

I am real new to the Storm. I have a requirement which is very similar as follows,

Lets say I have a biding system like in any e-commerce site where we can bid on any product. I get a load lets say 1Million requests per second. Now I need to get two stats at real time and show it to the user in the UI.

1. The total number of bid so far (The user can bid twice, so we need consolidate).
2. The top ten bids and their corresponding users sorted based on Bid amount and timestamp.

All this stats needs to be real time and consistent. So I hope storm is up to it.
From my understanding, we can use a messaging queue like kafka to store the incoming bids as logs. Then some group of consumers can pick them up and persist it in any DB. 
But I need to know how the storm using its bolts can aggregate and find my top ten window and update it realtime, so I can pick it up and show in UI.

My initial effort was like,

Kafka -> BiddingSpout -> bolts(to filter based on current top ten) -> bolt -> update the results

Kafka -> BiddingSpout -> bolt(counter) -> bolt -> update the results

But I cant quite get, how the bolts will filter based the current top ten results which are getting updated very second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a sort of persistence layer(cache or a database) which can be shared by your bolts instances.One of your bolt(counter) will keep on updating the count for a particular bid Id in that persistence layer,you need an atomic operation for this to read and increment(something like redis cache has it predefined).When the bid time is up you shouldn't receive any more messages and count should not be updated more for that bid id.Your other bolt(filter) should poll the persistence layer for bid time and as soon as it exceeds your bid time, you should get the count and update results where it needs to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, but we can see a kind of bottleneck where the count is stored in the cache right ? like a million requests updating the same cache object in a second atomically. I was hoping if storm can handle this somehow.

Comment: I think you are correct about that bottle neck,even with a cache things will be slow

Comment: One possible approach though i am not sure can be counting in partition you count or update data locally in partitions and then after you are done locally use some sort of tick tuples to update the persistence